# Change Main page grid's background color from settings page instantly .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

new to MAUI, i have a MainPage and i have a Settings page, lets say i want to change the background color of a grid inside MainPage. xaml from Settings page and have its affect applied instantly. how can i do it?

i already know how to apply it on app restart by assigning the grid a name and then assign the new color to grid's background on MainPage's constructor using preferences .  but how can i apply it without having to restart the app?

I've tried accessing it directly from settings page but that didn't work.

Comment: Use data binding, or just set the property directly.  Since you didn’t post any code demonstrating what you tried it’s impossible to say what you’re doing wrong

Comment: i've tried data binding like this grid   <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding MainPageGridColor}"  MainPageGridColor is a type Color , but it doesnt work, ive tried binding to a string hex value of color but that didnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DynamicResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming) for this, You can define the Color and Then change it from SettingsPage and it will be updated, You can define your colors in your App.Xaml

```
<Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#2196F3</Color>
<Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">#FFC107</Color>
```

And then update it on runtime

```
Application.Current.Resources["PrimaryColor"] = Color.Red;
```

This Color should be used in your Controls with the DynamicResource keyword

```
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i should've clarified that im using a color picker from inside the settings page to change the background color i don't want to pre-define a set of colors, i want the user to change the color from the color picker. I've tried data binding but it doesn't change it .

Comment: Doesn't matter you can use any color here

Comment: but how do bind the value of x:Key? so it changes to a new color?

Comment: Do you have like infinite number of backgrounds? if not shouldn't one suffice

Comment: this worked great but since i'm new to MAUI, i just got confused on how i should set the key to a new color, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your .xaml.cs of Settings page:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(Colors.BlueViolet));
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage (Color backgroundColor)
{
   InitializeComponent ();
   grid.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: this almost worked i had to add the Color service . but all it does is create a new main page navigates to it changes that  page color . the actual main page which is accessed using a TabBar doesnt change color.